# What is this italic serif font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, serif

I've now spent hours on the internet trying to find this font. I've done a font finder search by uploading the image to various websites to determine the font. Even after all these attempts, I still can't find the font.

Here is an image:

[image: Serif Font]

Can a graphic designer please help me out on this one or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Where is the image from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried WhatTheFont with no luck but I knew I recognised the font so I had a look through some fonts I had recently been looking through and here it is:

## [Prangs Black by Sudtipos](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sudtipos/prangs/)

[image: Prangs Black by Sudtipos]

Comment: Glad to help :)